# For Gradle Plugin (non core plugin), how to decide the version for each of them?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I begin to use Gradle to build my Spring boot project. I want to use the new plugin block format.

May I know how to find out these correct version of each (non core) plugin.

To build a spring boot project, I need to use below 2 plugin:
  org.springframework.boot
  io.spring.dependency-management

Originally, I use the legacy plugin config. My code looks like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

In above config, there is no need for me to provide the version for plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management'.

But if I use below new plugin block. My code may looks like below:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}
```

I have to provide version for plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management'.

**My question is:

 

How do I know the which version of 'io.spring.dependency-management' I should use?

Which version works well or compatibility well with 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'?**

Answer (score 0):

[org.springframework.boot](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot) is currently at version `2.1.7.RELEASE`;

The [documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) also shows the current version number.

[io.spring.dependency-management](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) might be optional plugin:

> A Gradle plugin that provides Maven-like dependency management functionality

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to just use [**Spring Initializr**](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/) and pick the version values (along with *"starters"* and more) right from there.

You can either use the online version at [**start.spring.io**](https://start.spring.io/) or use [`curl` to fetch right from your terminal](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#command-line).

---

Alternatively, you can see list of [supported versions](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn) in the documentation.

To use a specific version, just apply the following -

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE' // release as of 08-Aug-2019
}
```

Quoting from [Spring Boot Gradle plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/),

> Applied in isolation the plugin makes few changes to a project. Instead, the plugin detects when certain other plugins are applied and reacts accordingly. For example, when the `java` plugin is applied a task for building an executable jar is automatically configured.
>
> A typical Spring Boot project will apply the `groovy`, `java`, or `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` plugin and the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin as a minimum.

For a `java` project, you would do -

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

---

So, to use a specific version of Spring & Spring Boot, your `build.gradle` file would need a bare minimum of the following -

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
}
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

//...
```

Also, if you wish to use a pre-release / snapshot version, you'll need to add Spring's repositories -

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }
  resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
      if (requested.id.id == 'org.springframework.boot') {
        useModule("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you use the [**Spring Initializr**](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/) all this is handled for you!

Answer (score 0):

I am still using SpringBoot 1.5.x these days, and I found that when apply 'org.springframework.boot' plugin the dependency-management plugin will apply automatically with compatible version.

Screenshot of corresponding codes lists below :
[image]